# WinSCP - ignore single directory during sync

Tags: winscp

I have a directory on a server that needs to synchronize its contents to a client. It is set to delete files on the client that have also been deleted from the directory that is to be synced from the server.

I want to ignore a specific directory, so it does not delete its contents on the client.

The following script (located on the client) currently deletes the contents located in `/files/synced/oss/test/` but I want that directory to keep its contents on the client.

```
option exclude "Thumbs.db; /files/synced/oss/test/"
synchronize local -delete "D:\files" "/files/synced"
```

Comment: Note the `synched` vs. `synced`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl typo fixed in my original post, sorry for that

Comment: `synchronize local -delete` never deletes anything on the server, only on the local machine. If you have a different experience, include a session log file proving that.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - That is right, the content is deleted on the `local` part, that works fine on "server 2" in my case. But I want to try and ignore a directory located on "server 1". `/files/synced/oss/test/` on "server 2" ends up empty after the script ran.

Comment: So you ware synchronizing files between "server 1" and "server 2" via a local intermediate copy? If that's the case, we need to see both scripts. Or are you referring to the local machine by one of the "servers"? Which one?

Comment: Did my answer help? I understand now why your question was so confusing. It's quite a bad practice to call a machine, where you connect *from*, a *server*. It's a *client* from a perspective of your question, no matter that you consider it a *server* in general.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - Thank you for your answer, I have edited my original question and I hope it is more clear for others now as well. I will let you know once I have a result.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - Sorry for my late reply. Your solution worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you do not want to exclude a remote folder `/files/synced/oss/test/`.

You want to exclude a local folder `D:\files\oss\test\`.

Also note that the `option exclude` has been deprecated, use [`-filemask` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize#filemask) instead.

```
synchronize local -delete -filemask="| Thumbs.db; D:\files\oss\test\" "D:\files" "/files/synced"
```